# How to pass tab index value from UITabBarController to UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

I've created tab bar items in the first controller

```
UITabBarController *tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
tabBarController.delegate = self;
tabBarController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460);

StageViewController *stageViewRegular = [[StageViewController alloc] init];
[stageViewRegular setTitle:@"Regular"];
stageViewRegular.tabBarItem.tag = 1;

StageViewController *stageViewAdvanced = [[StageViewController alloc] init];
[stageViewAdvanced setTitle:@"Advanced"];
stageViewAdvanced.tabBarItem.tag = 2;

NSArray* controllersArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:stageViewRegular, stageViewAdvanced,  nil];
tabBarController.viewControllers = controllersArray;

tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0;
[self.view addSubview:tabBarController.view];
```

and I want to pass tabBarItem.tag to the controllers as mentioned above

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
    chooseLevel = viewController.tabBarItem.tag;
}
```

but in the second controller

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

    NSLog(@"%d", chooseLevel);
}
```

the chooseLevel always record old value. If I press the first tab and then press the second tab, the value in chooseLevel is 1 rather than 2.

Does anyone know how to solve it?

Comment: I found the two ViewControllers access viewDidLoad first, then get  the value I pass. But still don't know how to solve.

Comment: Try - (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tbController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    return YES;
}

Comment: thanks for your reply, but it doesn't work. maybe I should pass value first then push to another view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the following steps :

**AppDelegate.m**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    UIViewController *viewController1 = [[[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    viewController1.tabBarItem.tag = 0;
    UIViewController *viewController2 = [[[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    viewController2.tabBarItem.tag = 1;
    self.tabBarController = [[[UITabBarController alloc] init] autorelease];
    self.tabBarController.viewControllers = @[viewController1, viewController2];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

**FirstViewController.m**

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    NSLog(@"%d",self.tabBarItem.tag);
}
```

**SecondViewController.m**

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    NSLog(@"%d",self.tabBarItem.tag);
}
```

**OutPut :**

2013-06-27 18:13:03.913 sampletabs[3981:c07] 0

2013-06-27 18:13:05.282 sampletabs[3981:c07] 1

Thanks, Do let me know it works for you ?

Comment: OK, I create new project using your answer, and it works. But how do I create this tabBarController in the second view and pass messages to third view?

Comment: Finally, I just create three new controllers to solve it. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use selectedIndex property of the UITabBarController. I think it has the value you are trying to use.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 0):

```
You can use selected index property like this:

- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
    chooseLevel = tabBarController.selected index;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

    int selectedtag=self.tabBarController.selectedIndex;
    NSLog(@"%d", selectedtag);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this :

**RootViewController.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    UITabBarController *tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    tabBarController.delegate = self;
    tabBarController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460);

    FirstViewController *stageViewRegular = [[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil];
    [stageViewRegular setTitle:@"First"];
    stageViewRegular.tabBarItem.tag = 1;

    SecondViewController *stageViewAdvanced = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
    [stageViewAdvanced setTitle:@"Second"];
    stageViewAdvanced.tabBarItem.tag = 2;

    NSArray* controllersArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:stageViewRegular, stageViewAdvanced,  nil];
    tabBarController.viewControllers = controllersArray;

    tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0;
    [self.view addSubview:tabBarController.view];
}

- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
    NSLog(@"%d",viewController.tabBarItem.tag);
}
```

**FirstViewController**

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    NSLog(@"viewWillAppear %d",self.tabBarItem.tag);
}
```

**SecondViewController**

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    NSLog(@"viewWillAppear %d",self.tabBarItem.tag);
}
```

If you need Global value of selected tab Index, then create readWrite property in AppDelegate and set the value in either RootViewController or First/SecondViewController.you will get global value of ChooseLevel.

Thanks,